# About invertible functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

For $n\geq 2$, let $B=\{x\in \mathbb R^n:\|x\|_2\leq 1\}$ and $f(x)=\|x\|_2^2x$ for all $x\in B$. I want to show that $f:B\to B$ is differentiable and invertible but $f^{-1}:B\to B$ is not differentiable at $0$.

I can prove the invertibility of $f$. But how to show that $f^{-1}$ is not differentiable at $0$? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

$f^{-1}$ will not be differentiable at 0 if $f'(0)=0$, since we know that 
$f^{-1}\cdot f =1$.
Then $f'(x)h = (x,x)h+2(x,h)x$. And indeed at $0$, $f'(0)h=0h+0=0$.

This just generalizes the fact that on $[-1,1]$, $f:x\mapsto x^3$ is differentiable and invertible, but because $f'(0)=0$, $f^{-1}$ is not differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $g=f^{-1}:B\rightarrow B$ is given by
\begin{align}
g(y)=f^{-1}(y) = \frac{y}{\|y\|^{2/3}}
\end{align}
since
\begin{align}
f^{-1}\circ f (x) = \frac{\|x\|^2 x}{\|\|x\|^2x\|^{2/3}} = x \ \ \text{ and } \ \ f\circ f^{-1}(y) = \left\|\frac{y}{\|y\|^{2/3}}\right\|^2 \frac{y}{\|y\|^{2/3}} = y.
\end{align}
It's clear that $f^{-1}(y)$ is not differentiable at $y = 0$. Suppose it's differentiable then there exists a linear map $L$ such that 
\begin{align}
0=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\left\|g(h)-g(0)-L(h)\right\|}{\|h\|} .
\end{align}
But, by the reverse triangle inequality, we have that
\begin{align}
\frac{\left\|g(h)-g(0)-L(h)\right\|}{\|h\|} = \frac{\left\|\frac{h}{\|h\|^{2/3}}-L(h)\right\|}{\|h\|} \geq\left| \frac{1}{\|h\|^{2/3}}-\frac{\|L(h)\|}{\|h\|}\right|
\end{align}
and 
\begin{align}
\frac{\|L(h)\|}{\|h\|} \leq \frac{\|L\|\|h\|}{\|h\|} = \|L\|
\end{align}
which means as $h\rightarrow 0$
\begin{align}
\frac{\|g(h)-g(0)-L(h)\|}{\|h\|}\rightarrow \infty.
\end{align}